# CSS on wordpress not behaving using Chrome or Safari

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome, safari

A webpage I'm working on for a client www.afterthemagic.com (slightly NSFW) looks OK in Firefox & IE but I can't for the life of me make it look properly in Chrome or Safari. I'm trying to mess with different variables the following element in style.css, but can't seem to get it to go.

```
#banner-text .left span {
font-size: 96px;
font-style: normal;
text-transform: uppercase;
position: static;
}
```

Any pointers on how to get the "THE" text to look fine in Chrome or Safari?? Thanks!

Comment: Did you tried position:initial;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would argue that you're going about this layout incorrectly.

Semantically speaking, you shouldn't be combining your H1 heading with the 'begin reading' link.

Your heading, 'begin reading' and author subsections should be floated and styled independently.  Otherwise, I'm not sure what you mean by 'look properly'. Your h1 heading has a font-size of 200px, and your h1 .left span has a font-size of 96px.  If you're referring to the text alignment, try:

```
#banner-text h1 .left span {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0 0 10px 0;
  font-size: 96px;
  font-style: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Play with the margins until you get the alignment you're looking for.

This is a good resource to better understand the CSS 'display' property:
http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/